# Which permissions are needed to delete a file in windows

Tags: c++, winapi, file-permissions

In CreateFile() has DesiredAccess Like GENERIC_READ, GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES, etc.

My question is what is the minimum/exact permissions needed to solely delete a file in the system?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want to delete a file, use the [`DeleteFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363915%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function.

It's documentation details what permissions you need, and a few things you should know, like:

> If you request delete permission at the time you create a file, you can delete or rename the file with that handle, but not with any other handle.

There is good information in that documentation page, including a link to [File Security and Access Rights](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364399%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Look at the [`ACCESS_MASK`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa374892%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) page linked from the `OpenFile` documentation page for the actual delete access right flag - it's simply called `DELETE`.

But a word of warning: this type of check is always racy. The file permissions can change between your access right check and a subsequent delete. ([Time of check/time of use](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-of-check-to-time-of-use).)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.
DeleteFile deletes the file, and that is not what I want. I just want to know what is the file permission in CreateFile that allows me to delete (checking if I can delete the file, not actually deleting it).
I already checked MSDN...

Answer (score 2):

You only need `DELETE` access, I believe. It's not a file access right, it's a standard access right.

It's not easily found that these standard access rights are allowed, but the [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg258116%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on file access rights states:

> The valid access rights for files and directories include the DELETE, READ_CONTROL, WRITE_DAC, WRITE_OWNER, and SYNCHRONIZE standard access rights.